# Okta Authentication Django redirect

Tags: django, authentication, okta

I am implementing OpenID with Okta, but I am experiencing some issues with the redirect.

Basically I can see in the Okta admin page that the authorization was successful:[okta log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FXDV.png)

But the login won't redirect to the specified url.
Here are the settings in okta admin for the application: [Okta settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEp8Q.png)

The login page with the widget:

```
div id="okta-login-container"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var oktaSignIn = new OktaSignIn({
          baseUrl: '{{config.url}}',
          clientId: '{{config.clientId}}',
          redirectUri: '{{config.redirectUri}}',
          authParams: {
              issuer: '{{config.issuer}}',
              responseType: ['code'],
              scopes: "{{config.scope}}".split(" "),
              pkce: false,
          },
      });
      oktaSignIn.renderEl(
          {el: '#okta-login-container'},
          function (res) {
              console.log(res);
          })
    </script>
```

My okta settings in the app:

```
"REDIRECT_URI": "http://localhost:8000/callback",
    "LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL": "http://localhost:8000/profile", # default
    "CACHE_PREFIX": "okta", # default
    "CACHE_ALIAS": "default", # default
    "PUBLIC_NAMED_URLS": (), # default
    "PUBLIC_URLS": (), # default
    "USE_USERNAME": False, # default
```

The project URLS:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(("okta_oauth2.urls", "okta_oauth2"), namespace="okta_oauth2")),
    path('', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path('', include('request.urls')),
```

The app urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.login, name='login'),
    path('request_form/', views.request_form, name='request_form'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
```

The views:

```
def login(request):
    return render(request,'okta_oauth2/login.html', {})
```

And my folder structure: [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfiio.png)

This is what I get in the terminal when I log in:

```
[06/Jun/2021 17:35:06] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2012
[06/Jun/2021 17:35:09] "GET /callback?code=aL7yGY48sTPR7n5fKtciUlJfIwRIsyhuB2ADFD1ruDA&state=oa4dsoLnayMWPZ02N20DxNABenXif8QASQXy4vvdoep9MbvaLFh5gIbaRPzdQdeU HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[06/Jun/2021 17:35:09] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2012
```

I have this in the page where I want to redirect:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

Can someone see what am I missing? or what am I doing wrong? Do you need more information?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

After long research...

I was just missing to meet the requirement of the endpoint on the URI_REDIRECT

Just needed to add default after callback

"REDIRECT_URI": "http://localhost:8000/callback/default",